# Why have I got an increased row count after LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Im trying to JOIN together various datasets to get a master table, though I managed to preserve the row count after 3 left joins, but after the next step, it seems to increase it. Any ideas why?

Query with 3 Joins

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
--- STEP 4:    ----------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
DISTINCT        Table1.[Field1]
        ,   Table1.[Field2]
        ,   Table3.[Field3]
        ,   Table1.[Field4]
        ,   Table1.[Field5]
        ,   Table1.[Field6]
        ,   Table1.[Field7]
        ,   Table1.[Field8]
        ,   Table1.[Field9]
        ,   Table1.[Field10]
FROM        db1.dbo.raw_tbl_1 AS Table1
LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_2 Table2
ON          Table1.Field7 = Table2.[Field13]
    LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_3 Table3
    ON          CONVERT(INT,Table1.[Field2]) = Table3.Field14
        LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_4Table4
        ON          Table2.Field17= Table4. Field15
WHERE       Table2. Field17 IS NOT NULL
-- 2682270 rows (Desired row count)
```

Query with 4 Joins (The one that increases row count)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
--- STEP 5:    ----
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT
DISTINCT        Table1.[Field1]
        ,   Table1.[Field2]
        ,   Table3.[Field3]
        ,   Table1.[Field4]
        ,   Table1.[Field5]
        ,   Table1.[Field6]
        ,   Table1.[Field7]
        ,   Table5.[Field11]
        ,   Table6.[Field12]
        ,   Table1.[Field8]
        ,   Table1.[Field9]
        ,   Table1.[Field10]
FROM        db1.dbo.raw_tbl_1 AS Table1
LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_2 Table2
ON          Table1.Field7 = Table2.[Field13]
    LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_3 Table3
    ON          CONVERT(INT,Table1.[Field2]) = Table3. Field14
        LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_4 Table4
        ON          Table2. Field17= Table4. Field15
            LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_5 Table5
            ON          Table4. Field18= Table5. Field16
                LEFT JOIN   db2.dbo.tbl_6 Table6
                ON          Table5.[Field11] = CONVERT(INT,Table6.[Table6])
WHERE       Table2.Field17 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: because of a 1-many relationship.

Answer (score 17):

If one of the tables in the LEFT JOIN has more than one corresponding value, it will create a new row. If you don't want this behaviour, you need to use an aggregating function and `GROUP BY`.

More specifically, if you make a query using only the last tables you joined (the ones that cause the new rows), you'll be able to find the duplicate rows and decide how you want to handle that.

---

Since you mention that the last join is causing the problem, it means that Table6 is returning more rows than you expect it to. You'll have to do something like:

```
    SELECT Table5.Field11, COUNT(Table6.Table6) AS row_count
    FROM Table5
    LEFT JOIN  db2.dbo.tbl_6 Table6
        ON Table5.[Field11] = CONVERT(INT,Table6.[Table6])
    GROUP BY Field11
    HAVING row_count > 1
```

(the `HAVING` clause assume you're expecting a 1 to 1 correspondence between the tables. If not, leave it out). You'll have to manually scan for where Table6 returns more rows than you'd expected, then either modify your query or delete data accordingly.

Comment: Table6.[Field12] is of type in so I tried doing a MIN(Table6.[Field12]) and the grouping by the other columns, but i still get the same row count.

Comment: Then you haven't found what's causing the extra rows. It can be a column that you are not SELECTing, as long as it exists in the table, it can cause the duplicates.

I would make a query that selects everything from both tables and parse the rows until the duplicate columns are found.

Comment: The row count works fine up to the last join. If Table6 had an ID field and a description field, if there are IDs with the same descriptions or NULLs, could that be the reason for the increased row count?

Comment: I've added to my answer.